# How to detect that image element is in view? (jQuery Mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to overcome images size download limit on mobile devices by detecting if an image is in view and then downloading it. Also need to do the opposite and replace image src with a smaller image to release the memory. Does anyone know how to best detect image in view and opposite under jQuery Mobile?

Ps. I'm trying to work with [unveil.js](http://luis-almeida.github.com/unveil/) but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean the images within the active page. In that case, this will retrieve all images contained in it:

```
$.mobile.activePage.find('img');
```

EDIT:

```
$.mobile.activePage.find('img').each(function(index, el){
    var pos = $(el).position().top;
    var current = $(window).scrollTop();
    var height = $(window).height();
    if((pos > current) && (pos < current + height)) {
         // the image is in the viewport
    } else {
         // the image is not in the viewport
    }
});
```

Comment: No, I mean images in actual view.

Comment: What do you mean with view? The whole html?

Comment: viewport (visible part of page)

Comment: Thanks! I'll test the code tomorrow as it's time to go home here now... :)